# Is SQL UPDATE transitive?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Does Sql server prevent updating the same row multiple times in the same single execution ending in different results?

If one table has rows like:

```
1
2
3
```

And one update is perfomed to change all '1's to '2's and all '2's to '3's, would it be possible to have the first row changed to '2' and then have it again changed to '3' ending with all rows with '3' values?

Testing in SQL Server with:

```
create table t ( c1 int );
insert into t (c1) values (1);
insert into t (c1) values (2);
insert into t (c1) values (3);

update t
set c1 = 
    case 
        when c1 = 1 then 2 
        when c1 = 2 then 3 
        else c1 
    end
;

select * 
from t;
```

The result sugest only one logic update for each value.

But I'm considering that in this case all values are in the same page (because is a small set). But if they are in different pages AND one index is being used to scan the rows during the update maybe it is possible that a value that is updated in the begining of the execution is pushed forward in the index to a different page and visited again in this same execution. If that happens that row may be updated several times ending in different results.

My tests do not show this behavior but I cannot find if this is enforced by SQL Server or that my tests are working by some ocassional execution plans that happen to prevent that.

One can prevent this by updating to a different column or using other techniques, I'm justing asking if I can trust in SQL Server to prevent this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After futherer investigation it seems that SQL Server have a protection to this kind of behavior.

The problem is well known and even got the ["Halloween Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem) name.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/02/27/halloween-protection.aspx) post describes the way SQL Server solves this.

So, the programmer should be able to trust that SQL Server will prevent this - the Halloween Problem. No need to have aditional columns or temp table.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL (and all major relational databases) are transactional in nature. Sometimes the transaction is implicit. It can however be strictly controlled by BEGIN TRANS, COMMIT and ROLLBACK statements. TRANSACTION can be both nested and distributed (accross separate databses and servers). MS SQL runs the NASDEQ so although many bankers would like it not to be transactionaly secure allowing them to effectively print money, the MS techies have won this. The basic MSSQL core is the same for all versions of MS SQL especially the Transaction bit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx refers

Simple answer is Yes

Comment: This is all in the same transaction. Either result would not violate the transactionality of the update. I think it is just a question about the semantic of the update statement. Does it garanties only one update for each row (and is so, which one).

Comment: Your statement is wrapped in an implicit transaction. It will perform the case operation once on the set. There is no recursion. c1 will be evaluted for the initial set, the result will be written to a "copy" of your data, which will then be switched to or forgotten when the single atomic operation of commit or rollback is invoked. In your statement, the begin transaction and commit is implicit. If you wrap your statement in an explicit transaction and pause it before the commit, then do a (separate) select with "read dirty" hint, you will see both versions of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can trust the database to be completely predictable in this case.

The database will update each record with the result from the `case` expression, so each record will only be updated once.

It will not break up the `case` expression to make it a multiple step update where it finds records to update depending on the values, i.e. it won't turn it into:

```
update t
set c1 = 2
where c1 = 1;
update t
set c1 = 3
where c1 = 2
```

Comment: The case is just an example. It could be presented with joins, like:

The execution should track what rows were already updated. But there are some cases that the same row is updated multiple time (in other situations).

Comment: I posted one query that can potencial update the same row multiple times (I cannot edit it properly because the site does not like "union all sel.ct": [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280518/sql-update-same-row-multiple-times)